# No taskbar, nonfunctional Start menu, no shortcuts - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, task-manager

I fear I've encountered a fatal error on my computer; while trying to make space on my CPU by ending tasks on my Task Manager, I closed Windows Explorer as I didn't need it, and it kept reappearing. At one point, the taskbar disappeared, but then reappeared as Windows Explorer also reappeared as a task on the list. 
Now my Start menu won't work, WIN+E won't work, I can't access Windows Explorer through FL Studio (the only remaining program open) despite trying to open a browser window through choosing an application to open an add-on file. 
The background is the theme colour alone, and nothing works. How can I fix this safely? The method CANNOT involve restarting, as the FL Studio session is in a demo version and so despite being saved will be unreopenable.

Comment: Does ctrl+alt+del work?

Comment: Would this not cause a restart on Windows 8?

Comment: Edit: access to an 'Open with' window is available currently

Comment: No. It should allow you to run task manager. Then you can do file > New task > Explorer.exe. See [How to Use the New Task Manager in Windows 8 or 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/108742/how-to-use-the-new-task-manager-in-windows-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the volatility of my situation, a question was necessary. However all is amended and here is the solution. 
Find any way to open a browser window. I went to an add on, right clicked, 'Open with', then navigate to C:\Windows\explorer.exe'.
Taskbar icons will slowly reappear.